# WPF SoundPlayer multi-channel sound?

Tags: wpf, soundplayer

I have an app that emits sounds at a random interval. When two sounds collide they do not nicely overplay each other but one interrupts the other.

I'm using SoundPlayer to play the sounds. (this is a WPF app)

How can I use multiple sound channels so that if two sounds occur at the same time they are both played at the same time instead of one interrupting the other?

Comment: usually multi-channel refers to separate speakers. do you look forward for the same? or you are looking for multiple stream of sounds playing simultaneously?

Comment: I'm looking for two sounds playing at the same time. I have multiple sounds that occur almost at the same time and would like them to overlap. Right now the second sound cuts the first one short.

Comment: try playing the different sounds using different players.

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work. 
Task.Run(() =>
{
    var player =
        new SoundPlayer(@"c:\Computer_Magic.wav");
    player.Play();
});

Put that on a button and click it and you'll see it will interrupt the first call.

Comment: as an alternative try using `MediaElement` also, may it solve your issue.

Comment: Yeah I tried it but the same issue. It seems the MediaElement and Soundplayer both use a single channel. What is required is multi-channel sound such as in XNA. Unfortunately XNA is discontinued, so I suppose the only real choice is DirectX currently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To my knowledge `SoundPlayer` uses the native [PlaySound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743680(v=vs.85).aspx) function which does not support playing multiple sound simultaneously.

You can however do this with `System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer`.

```
var p1 = new MediaPlayer();
p1.Open(new Uri(@"C:\windows\media\ringout.wav"));
p1.Play();

System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250);

var p2 = new MediaPlayer();
p2.Open(new System.Uri(@"C:\windows\media\ringout.wav"));
p2.Play();
```

The sleep is there simply to add a bit of a delay to the playback, making it clear that the two sounds do actually play at the same time.

Comment: How does the delay show that they are playing at the same time?

Comment: Could have swore I tried that, but thank you so much, enjoy the bounty!

Comment: @Trevor It'll will start playing the second sound 250 milliseconds later than the first one, making it easier for us humans to hear that the two sounds do actually overlap. You could probably hear it without the sleep, but it wouldn't be as obvious.